# mysql workbench error saving imported table

Tags: mysql, sql, workbench

I'm trying to import a csv file to mysql, everything is working fine except i'm missing some rows. Once the import is done I apply the table and it gives me an error "33 errors saving changes to table..."

I have 1636 rows, when i click apply the table is imported and I can select from it except it's missing 33 rows, the error message doesn't tell me what's wrong.

Comment: In line with the error that appears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both [SHOW ERRORS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-errors.html) and [SHOW WARNINGS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-warnings.html) to see what goes wrong when running your queries.

For example,

```
SHOW ERRORS;
```

Would show the errors for the last batch of SQL statements you executed.